# Setting Membership Store Passwords

Tags: asp.net, sql, membership

I'm migrating an application from ColdFusion to ASP.Net MVC and have a little problem I cannot seem to get my head around.  The original application stores user's passwords in a MD5 hash format with no salt in the database.  I'm using the ASP.Net membership store and would like to allow for as seamless a transition for the existing users as possible.  Here's the possibilities I was thinking of...

1) Since I cannot decrypt the values of their current passwords, I was thinking of storing this old password in a table, checking against it on login... if it's not empty and their password matches, I prompt them to update their password, which would then set the password properly in the asp.net membership table and wipe out their old password, never to be checked again.

2) Users login with their email, not their screen name, so I was thinking of resetting everyone's password to their screen name and forcing them to change it after first login.  The only problem is that I'm not sure I can update their password via SQL without the current password.  Executing the aspnet_Membership_SetPassword proc doesn't appear to encrypt the password in its own.

What you say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used a variant of #1 in a live application. It worked great, users never noticed the change as far as I was aware.

A couple of refinements:

- You don't need to prompt them to update their password; they provided you the cleartext to log in (and you know it's the correct cleartext since it hashed correctly), so just go ahead and set that as their password.
- Make sure you clear the legacy password hash if they use the password reset functionality.

I would under no circumstances use option 2; it's wildly insecure.

One other thing -- it is possible to set a password without knowing their current one, it just requires two steps.

1. Reset the user's password. You now know the reset password.
2. Use the newly reset password to set the password to a known value.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation recently- An old application of mine used a salted MD5 and I very much wanted to upgrade without affecting my users. What I ended up doing was wrapping the original hash in a better hash and then re-salting it to mitigate the loss of resolution.

For example my initial hash was MD5(pass + salt)

I upgraded everything to SHA256(MD5(pass+salt) +salt) - that way my app is secure and I never needed to find out the original passwords or reset anything.

Once your new authentication process is in place simply run an update script over all existing users in the DB. It is a little bit of a pain but is essentially seamless for you users.

--

Bah- I apologize, this isn't really tailored to ASP.net membership as I'm using a custom auth class on my application. I still think it is one of the more sound methods for performing the upgrade, but i'm not sure of the ASP.net membership specifics.

Comment: Yeah, ASP.NET doesn't give you that much control over how the password is hashed in the default providers; you could do it in a custom membership provider easily enough, though. Interesting solution.

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 is a pretty big security risk. If anyone knows the email of a screen name can log hijack that account before the rightful owner logs in. Knowing or guessing the email of most popular site users (ie. most tempting ones to hijack) may be more prevalent than you think.